# How to bind 1/0 instead of true/false on checked property of a checkbox

Tags: checkbox, knockout.js

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="value : 1, checked: FgActive" />
```

I want FgActive to be 1 and 0 instead of true and false. Is there a simple way of doing that?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing to do is to create a `ko.computed` that converts the checked boolean binding to/from a 1/0 numeric.

```
self.fgActiveNumeric = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return self.fgActive() == 1 ? true : false;
    },
    write: function (newValue) {
        self.fgActive(newValue ? 1 : 0);
    }
});
```

Use it like a normal `checked` binding:

```
<input type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: fgActiveNumeric' />
```

You can read more about this technique here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html

[**See the Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/blugrasmaniac/e58Sv/1/)

Comment: The first time I checked the input, the model reflected just fine, but the unchecked action didnt work. Thanks for your resonse!

Answer (score 2):

I came across a solution. I created a custom binding that works on the update, after the checked binding. Dont know if is the best solution, but worked just fine.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.NumChecked = {
    update: function (element, valueAccesor) {
        var func = valueAccesor();
        if (typeof (func) == 'function' && func() == true)
            func(1);
        else if ((typeof (func) == 'function'))
            func(0);
    }
};

<input type="checkbox" data-bind="NumChecked: FgActive, checked: FgActive" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it, using jQuery:

```
var myVal = ( $('#myCheckbox').is(':checked') ) ? 1 : 0;

alert('myVal is: ' +myVal); //alerts 1 if checked, 0 if not checked
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tjyntj1b/)</kbd>